# How to handle null exception in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

hey i have some fields in which i am binding my model with html and data coming from backend.
but when i click to edit the data it always say cannot read value of null.
how can i handle this?

**here is my html**

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="patient?.Address.Address1" name="address1"
             class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="address1"
             placeholder="Address1" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="patient?.Address.Address2" name="address2"
             class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="address2"
             placeholder="Address 2" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="patient?.Address.City" name="city"
                 class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="city" inputName
                 placeholder="City" [required]="isOfficeStaff">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <select [(ngModel)]="patient?.Address.State" name="state"
                  [ngClass]="{'text-dimmed': !patient?.Address.State}"
                  class="form-control input-underline input-lg">
            <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>State</option>
            <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.abbreviation">
              {{state.abbreviation}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="patient?.Address.Zip" name="zip"
                 class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="zipcode" maxlength="5"
                 pattern="\d{5}" placeholder="Zipcode" [required]="isOfficeStaff">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**here is the model**

```
export class Patient {
 id?: number;
 Email?: string;
 Address? = {
   Address1: '',
   Address2: '',
   City: '',
   State: '',
   Zip: '',
   County: '',
   Country: ''
   };
 }
```

**ts file**

```
public patient: Patient;

ngOnInit() {

  this.store.select("patient").subscribe(patient => {
    this.patient = Object.assign({}, new Patient(), patient);
    if (this.patient.Id && !this.patientSnapshot) {
      this.patientSnapshot = {...this.patient};
    }
  });

 });
}
```

when i open to edit the address 
it throws an error 
**cannot read property address 1 of null** 
is there any way to handle this error even if the value coming from is null or empty string?
thanks

Comment: can't you do a [(ngModel)]="patient?.Address.Address1 | null" or something like that? doesn't sound too complicated to me, you either set to a default value when nothing comes back or just deal with a null/undefined/empty string.

Comment: i know sounds easy and i also would have done it but cannot seem to handle it.

Comment: Is that the only field where this fails or is it failing only there because that one is the first binding?

Comment: no it is failing for every Address value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to use 2 way binding with an object that may not be there that also has a property that may not be there.  This doesn't work then using [(ngModel)] but can work if you split up the binding like this.

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="patient?.Address?.Address1" (ngModelChange)="functionToHandleSettingValue($event)" name="address1" >
```

in this way, you are handling the binding of data in with the ngModel and the binding of data out with ngModelChange.

Also note that in the ngModel the statement should be

```
[ngModel]="patient?.Address?.Address1"
```

with both an elvis operator on the patient and the Address since both are nullable.